# Auto increment field in context of foreign key

Tags: django, django-models

I am writing as an *(personal)* exercise a little Issue tracker in django.

I want to have for a model an integer field that is unique (auto incremented), but not for the whole model/table but in the context of a related model.

```py
class Parent(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10) 


class Child(models.Model): 
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, models.CASCADE) 
    identifier = models.IntegerField()
```

The goal is to have a parent classes with the names "ABC" and "XYZ". Now i want to create multiple instances of child classes and the identifiers should more or less auto increment in the context of the Parent class.

```
Instance #1: parent is "ABC" -> identifier = 1  
Instance #2: parent is "ABC" -> identifier = 2  
Instance #3: parent is "DEF" -> identifier = 1
```

How do i achieve this in a transaction safe manner?

Comment: While I'm sure this is possible, I don't really think Django is set up to achieve this by any default methods. Can I ask your reasoning for requiring the "strict" sequencing like this? Why can child ID not be just a standard auto-increment ID (i.e. the pk for Child ...)?

Comment: @urbanspaceman The goal is to address the child with ABC-1 or DEF-1

Comment: You mean in the URL? You can still do that with non-consecutive numbers.

Comment: First, add a `unique_together` constraint on `parent` + `identifier` (using `UniqueConstraint`), that way you'll enforce the uniqueness without having to worry too much about transactions. Second, set the `identifier` in the `pre_save()` method (and catch the error in the `save()` method to adjust the `identifier` if for some reason it clashes). But in the end, what happens when you delete an instance?

Comment: @dirkgroten thank you very much! I will try this attempt. I've now found F expressions and thought that's maybe also a possible solution in combination with your suggestions. To your question: The identifier should stay like it is. I want to prevent deleting and just deactivate a child.